# Ruby protected visibility calling from superclass

Tags: ruby, protected, nomethoderror

I have this little code that seems to contradict in some way [Ruby's documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Visibility):

> The second visibility is `protected`. When calling a protected method the sender must be a subclass of the receiver or the receiver must be a subclass of the sender. Otherwise a `NoMethodError` will be raised.

```
class Test
  def publico(otro)
    otro.prot
  end  
end

class Hija < Test
  protected def prot; end
end

Test.new.publico(Hija.new)
```

I get the folowing output:

> NoMethodError: protected method `prot' called for #
>     publico

What am I missing? Apparently the option " the receiver must be a subclass of the sender" is not available.

Comment: The code you wrote is actually not your original. It corresponds to the `a.n b` case in the example in the doc, which raises an exception, as described. There is conflict **within** the documentation (In that respect, your question is a bit misleading, but nevertheless raises a good point).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it does not work on Parent Class which know nothing of the protected method, it works on the Subclasses of Subclass which define the protected method. Eg.

```
class A
  def n(other)
    other.m
  end
end

class B < A
  def m
    1
  end

  protected :m

end

class C < B
end

class D < C
end

a = A.new
b = B.new
c = C.new
d = C.new

c.n b #=> 1 -- sender C is a subclass of B
b.n b #=> 1 -- m called on defining class
a.n b # raises NoMethodError although reciever B is  a subclass of sender A
b.n c #=> 1 -- reciever C is subclass of sender B
c.n d #=> 1 -- reciever D is sublcass of sender C
```

We can probably conclude that the behaviour is something like " either the sender or the reciever must have inherited the method". With that behivaour, we can explain that since neither A (which does not know the existence of m) nor B (which knows the existence but not inherited it) ineherited the method, it raises the error.

Although there is also a possibility that this could be a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Protected methods can only be called from instances of the same class or a subclass.  Hija is a subclass of Test.  Test is not a subclass of Hija.  So a protected method in Hija is not available to instances of Test.

So if your example were the other way:

```
class Hija
  protected def prot; end
end
class Test < Hija
  def publico(otro)
    otro.prot
  end
end
Test.new.publico(Hija.new)
```

works fine.